# Html Popup to add PWA icon to Phone

Tags: javascript, angular, service-worker, progressive-web-apps

Ok, I haven't found an answer to this.
I need to create a Popup in HTML that allows me to install the PWA Icon on the home screen, and I am not speaking of the regular install banner. 
I already know how to do this by using the manifest and the service worker.

Now, to understand this, what I need you can see this behavior when installing Instagram PWA.

1. Instagram shows this html popup, I guess that theres some sort of javacript code that gest fired when pressing the button, it fires the regular
   install banner.

[image: pwa install]

Any idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the PWA meets the requirements for adding to home screen, the browser fires a "beforeinstallprompt" event. The event may be caught and fired manually again at a later time. Basically: listen for the event, grab it if it fires, show the user your custom add to home screen view, if the user clicks re-fire the vent.

Specific details and code samples: https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/app-install-banners/